# Micro ORM on the lines of dapper

Tags: c#, dapper

Designing a micro ORM inspired by Dapper. I'm building this as an exercise to learn. I would appreciate if you guys can review my code.

I would also appreciate any suggestions regarding the features that can/should be added to this ORM. The source is available [here](https://github.com/learncode/Sublime).

> ConnectionStringProvider.cs

```
   public interface IDbConnectionStringProvider {
      ConnectionStringEntity GetConnectionString(string connectionStringKey);
   }

   public class ConnectionStringProvider : IDbConnectionStringProvider {
      public ConnectionStringEntity GetConnectionString(string connectionStringKey) {
         Require.NotNullOrEmptyString(connectionStringKey, @"Connection string cannot be empty.");
         Require.NotNull(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings, "Please provide a config file with a connection strings entry");

         ConnectionStringSettings settings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionStringKey];

         if (settings == null)
            throw new ConfigurationErrorsException(string.Format("Cannot find the connection string: [{0}] in the config file.", connectionStringKey));

         if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(settings.ConnectionString) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(settings.ProviderName))
            throw new ConfigurationErrorsException(string.Format("Require connection string as well as provider name to instantiate connection for Key [{0}].", connectionStringKey));

         return new ConnectionStringEntity() {ConnectionString = settings.ConnectionString, ProviderName = settings.ProviderName};
      }
   }
```

> ConnectionProvider.cs

```
   public interface IConnectionProvider : IDisposable {
      DbConnection CreateConnection(string connectionStringKey);
      DbDataAdapter Adapter { get; }
      IDbDataParameter CreateParameter();
   }

   public class ConnectionProvider : IConnectionProvider {

      IDbConnectionStringProvider _connectionStringProvider;
      DbProviderFactory _dbProviderFactory;
      DbConnection _dbConnection;
      DbDataAdapter _adapter;

      public ConnectionProvider(IDbConnectionStringProvider connectionStringProvider) {
         _connectionStringProvider = connectionStringProvider;
      }

      public DbDataAdapter Adapter {
         get {
            if (_dbConnection == null)
               throw new ObjectDisposedException("Connection object does not exist. Cannot return adapter object.");
            if (_adapter == null)
               throw new ObjectDisposedException("Adapter not initialized.");
            return _adapter;
         }
      }

      public DbConnection CreateConnection(string connectionStringKey) {
         Require.NotNullOrEmptyString(connectionStringKey, "Connection string is empty.");

         ConnectionStringEntity connectionStringEntity = _connectionStringProvider.GetConnectionString(connectionStringKey);
         _dbProviderFactory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(connectionStringEntity.ProviderName);

         Require.NotNull(_dbProviderFactory, "Provider factory cannot be null. Please provide a valid provider name.");

         _dbConnection = _dbProviderFactory.CreateConnection();
         _dbConnection.ConnectionString = connectionStringEntity.ConnectionString;
         _adapter = _dbProviderFactory.CreateDataAdapter();

         return _dbConnection;
      }

      public IDbDataParameter CreateParameter() {
         Require.NotNull(_dbProviderFactory, "Provider factory cannot be null. Please access this method with a valid connection.");
         return _dbProviderFactory.CreateParameter();
      }

      public void Dispose() {
         CloseConnection();
         GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
      }

      protected virtual void CloseConnection() {
         try {
            if (_dbConnection != null) {
               _dbConnection.Close();
               _dbConnection.Dispose();
               _adapter.Dispose();
            }
         } finally {
            _dbConnection = null;
            _adapter = null;
         }
      }

      ~ConnectionProvider() {
         CloseConnection();
      }
   }
```

> DbContext.cs

```
public interface IDbContext {
   List<T> Query<T>(string connectionStringKey, string query, List<Tuple<string, object>> parameters) where T : new();
   List<T> Procedure<T>(string connectionStringKey, string procedureName, List<Tuple<string, object, DbType, ParameterDirection>> parameters) where T : new();
   int ExecuteQuery(string connectionStringKey, string query, List<Tuple<string, object>> parameters);
}

public class DbContext : IDbContext {
   IConnectionProvider _connectionProvider;

   public DbContext(IConnectionProvider connectionProvider) {
      _connectionProvider = connectionProvider;
   }

   public List<T> Query<T>(string connectionStringKey, string query, List<Tuple<string, object>> parameters) where T : new () {
      IDbDataParameter[] dbParameters = null;
      if (parameters != null) {
         dbParameters = new IDbDataParameter[parameters.Count];
         for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Count; i++) {
            dbParameters[i] = CreateParameter(parameters[i].Item1, parameters[i].Item2);
         }
      }
      DataSet dataset = ExecuteDataSet(connectionStringKey, query, CommandType.Text, dbParameters);
      return Mapper.GetList<T>(dataset.Tables[0]);
   }

   public List<T> Procedure<T>(string connectionStringKey, string procedureName, List<Tuple<string, object, DbType, ParameterDirection>> parameters) where T : new() {
      IDbDataParameter[] dbParameters = null;
      if (parameters != null) {
         dbParameters = new IDbDataParameter[parameters.Count];
         for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Count; i++) {
            dbParameters[i] = CreateParameter(parameters[i].Item1, parameters[i].Item2, parameters[i].Item3, parameters[i].Item4);
         }
      }
      DataSet dataset = ExecuteDataSet(connectionStringKey, procedureName, CommandType.StoredProcedure, dbParameters);
      return Mapper.GetList<T>(dataset.Tables[0]);
   }

   public int ExecuteQuery(string connectionStringKey, string query, List<Tuple<string, object>> parameters) {
      int result = -1;
      IDbDataParameter[] dbParameters = null;
      if (parameters != null) {
         dbParameters = new IDbDataParameter[parameters.Count];
         for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Count; i++) {
            dbParameters[i] = CreateParameter(parameters[i].Item1, parameters[i].Item2);
         }
      }

      using(_connectionProvider) {
         using (DbConnection connection = _connectionProvider.CreateConnection(connectionStringKey)) {
            connection.Open();
            using (DbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand()) {
               command.CommandText = query;
               if (parameters != null) {
                  command.Parameters.AddRange(dbParameters);
               }
               result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
         }
      }

      return result;
   }

   private DataSet ExecuteDataSet(string connectionStringKey, string commandText, CommandType commandType, IDbDataParameter[] parameters) {
      DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
      using (_connectionProvider) {
         using (DbConnection connection = _connectionProvider.CreateConnection(connectionStringKey)) {
            connection.Open();
            using (DbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand()) {
               command.CommandText = commandText;
               command.CommandType = commandType;
               if (parameters != null) {
                  command.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
               }
               DbDataAdapter adapter = _connectionProvider.Adapter;
               adapter.SelectCommand = command;
               adapter.Fill(dataset);
            }
         }
      }
      return dataset;
   }

   private IDbDataParameter CreateParameter(string parameterName, object value, DbType dbType, ParameterDirection direction) {
      Require.NotNullOrEmptyString(parameterName, string.Format("Invalid arguments passed to the method. Parameter name: [{0}]", "(empty)"));

      IDbDataParameter param = this._connectionProvider.CreateParameter();
      param.ParameterName = parameterName.GetParameterName();
      param.Value = value;
      param.DbType = dbType;
      param.Direction = direction;
      return param;
   }

   private IDbDataParameter CreateParameter(string parameterName, object value) {
      Require.NotNullOrEmptyString(parameterName, string.Format("Invalid arguments passed to the method. Parameter name: [{0}]", "(empty)"));

      IDbDataParameter param = this._connectionProvider.CreateParameter();
      param.ParameterName = parameterName.GetParameterName();
      param.Value = value;
      return param;
   }
}
```

> Mapper.cs

```
public class Mapper {
   public static List<T> GetList<T>(DataTable dataTable) where T : new() {
      List<T> entities = new List<T>();

      foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows) {
         T obj = new T();
         foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in new T().GetType().GetProperties()) {
            var column = (Column)propertyInfo.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(Column));
            if (column == null)
               continue;
            propertyInfo.SetValue(obj, MassageValue(row[column.Name], propertyInfo.PropertyType));
         }
         entities.Add(obj);
      }

      return entities;
   }

   static object MassageValue(object o, Type t) {
      if (t == typeof(int)) {
         return o == DBNull.Value ? default(int) : o;
      }

      if(t == typeof(decimal)) {
         return o == DBNull.Value ? default(decimal) : o;
      }

      if (t == typeof(DateTime)) {
         return o == DBNull.Value ? default(DateTime) : o;
      }

      if (t == typeof(double)) {
         return o == DBNull.Value ? default(double) : o;
      }

      if (t == typeof(string)) {
         return o == DBNull.Value ? default(string) : o;
      }

      return o;
   }
}
```

> Example:

```
public class Customer {
   [Column(Name = "CustomerID")]
   public string CustomerId { get; set; }
   [Column(Name = "CompanyName")]
   public string CompanyName { get; set; }
   [Column(Name = "ContactTitle")]
   public string Title { get; set; }
   [Column(Name = "Region")]
   public string Region { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerOrderDetail {
   [Column(Name = "UnitPrice")]
   public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
   [Column(Name = "ProductName")]
   public string ProductName { get; set; }
   [Column(Name = "Quantity")]
   public int Quantity { get; set; }
   [Column(Name = "Discount")]
   public int Discount { get; set; }
   [Column(Name = "ExtendedPrice")]
   public decimal ExtendedPrice { get; set; }
}

DbContext context = new DbContext(new ConnectionProvider(new ConnectionStringProvider()));
string connectionStringKey = @"northwind";

#region Simple select query
string query = @"SELECT TOP 10 * FROM customers";
List<Customer> customers = context.Query<Customer>(connectionStringKey, query, null);
#endregion

#region Parametrized SQL query
string parameterizedQuery = @"SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID = @customerId";
string paramName = "customerId";
string customerId = @"ALFKI";
Tuple<string, object> t = new Tuple<string, object>(paramName, customerId);
customers = context.Query<Customer>(connectionStringKey, parameterizedQuery, new List<Tuple<string, object>>() { t });
#endregion

#region execute proc
Tuple<string, object, DbType, ParameterDirection> procedureParam = new Tuple<string, object, DbType, ParameterDirection>("OrderID", 10248, DbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Input);
List<CustomerOrderDetail> details = context.Procedure<CustomerOrderDetail>(connectionStringKey, "dbo.CustOrdersDetail", new List<Tuple<string, object, DbType, ParameterDirection>>() { procedureParam });
#endregion

#region insert/update/delete data
string insertQuery = @"insert into region (RegionID, RegionDescription)values (@regionId, @description)";
var valueTupleList = new List<Tuple<string, object>>();
Tuple<string, object> t1 = new Tuple<string, object>("regionId", 5);
Tuple<string, object> t2 = new Tuple<string, object>("description", "MidWestern");

int result = context.ExecuteQuery(connectionStringKey, insertQuery, new List<Tuple<string, object>>() { t1, t2 });

string updateQuery = @"UPDATE region SET RegionDescription = @description WHERE RegionID = @regionId";
t2 = new Tuple<string, object>("description", "Mid-Western");
result = context.ExecuteQuery(connectionStringKey, updateQuery, new List<Tuple<string, object>>() { t1, t2 });

string deleteQuery = @"DELETE FROM region WHERE RegionID = @regionId";
result = context.ExecuteQuery(connectionStringKey, deleteQuery, new List<Tuple<string, object>>() { t1 });
#endregion
```

Answer (score 2):

Some notes.

1. This piece of code `propertyInfo.SetValue(obj, MassageValue(row[column.Name], propertyInfo.PropertyType));` will trow exception for nullable types. Did you test it with classes with `int?` or `double?` properties ?
2. Client code with your Tuples are very hard to read ... Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017352/is-using-net-4-0-tuples-in-my-c-sharp-code-a-poor-design-decision). As for me, using `Tuple` for public methods is usually bad idea. I would like to have something like `SqlParameter` class there which encapsulates all parameter properties
3. I would recommend you to use `Dispose` according to official recommendations .. . Look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/b1yfkh5e(v=vs.110).aspx). Section "Basic Dispose pattern". It seems that your `Dispose` will work but at least it looks strange ...

Comment: I modified the SetValue to something like this, 

`propertyInfo.SetValue(obj, row[column.Name] == DBNull.Value ? null : row[column.Name]);`

This change works with nullable value types.

Comment: @LearnCode Glad for you :)